# Find the gradient sum function at $p = (1,..,1)$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I need to find the gradient of the function
$h(x_1,...,x_n)= \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_1x_i$ at $p = (1,...,1).$

I found out that for $x_1$, I would get:

$\frac{\partial\;x_1*x_1+x_1*x_2+...+x_1*x_n}{\partial x_1} = 2x_1 + x_2 + x_3+ ... + x_n$. If I plug in $x_1 = 1$, then:

$2*1+1+1+...+1 = n+1$

For $x_2$, $x_3$, ... I would get:

$\frac{\partial\;x_1*x_1+x_1*x_2+...+x_1*x_n}{\partial x_i} = x_1$. If I plug in $x_1 = 1$, then I would get: 1.

So can I conclude that the gradient would be $\nabla f(x_1,...,x_n) =  (n+1,1,1,...1)?$

Comment: Time to refer back to your textbook, and you seem to have a bit of confusion about what it is you're needing to compute the gradient of. I suppose you probably meant $h(x_1, \dots, x_n) = \cdots$

Comment: The problem is that my course doesn't have a textbook and I only have a few examples to learn from. But what would be your suggestion for this question?

Comment: @RicardoCavalcanti What do you think of my answer now?

Comment: @RicardoCavalcanti so it's correct? Great! Thanks for your help